# Removing Backbone View and Unbinding Events

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm recently started working in Backbone Library. The Backbone View currently I'm working on have child views so I thought I can override the `remove()` method and do the clean-up job there.

Here is the code,

```
var myView = Backbone.View.extend({
   ...

   remove: function(){
      this.childView1.remove();
      this.childView2.remove();

      Backbone.View.prototype.unbind.call(this);
      Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);
   }
});
```

On seeing some examples in SO, the order in which `unbind()` and `remove()` is called is reversed means first they are calling `remove()` and then `unbind()`. The order what I've above is correct or wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the order matters, all remove does is call,

```
remove: function() {
  this.$el.remove();
  this.stopListening();
  return this;
}
```

which removes the element form the DOM and removes any listeners,

and `.off()` (`.unbind()` is just a mask for `.off()`) just [removes all bound callbacks for all events](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-17) for the object. The order won't matter as the outcome will be the same.

It should be noted that as long as you are using `this.listenTo()` to register all your event listeners (You really should be), you don't even need to call `.off()`,

```
remove: function(){
   this.childView1.remove();
   this.childView2.remove();
   return Backbone.View.prototype.remove.call(this);
}
```